# Incorrect injection between beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ldap

I am attempting create two beans for ldap connections.

In my context.xml file I create two LdapContextSource and then auto wire two beans with same parent class , derived like the PersonDao and PersonDaoImpl in the spring ldap examples.

The issue I keep getting is that both beans end up with the same context source.  Even after I used @AutoWired @Qualifier .

The debug shows that both singleton beans see a different LdapContextSource but in the end both beans have same context.

**Is there an example somewhere that demonstrates how to wire two ldap connections via context.xml and @autowired methodology?**

I could do this just by programmatically assigning the ldapcontextsource in each class instance but I am trying to do this via @AutoWired.

Edited:

To make this clearer I paste some code samples from https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/18/ldaptemplate-java-ldap-made-simple.html
The beans to define the connection to ldap can be defined as follows:

```
<beans>
   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="the proper location of my code"/>
   <bean id="contextSource" class="net.sf.ldaptemplate.support.LdapContextSource">
      <property name="url" value="ldap://localhost:389" />
      <property name="base" value="dc=jayway,dc=se" />
      <property name="userName" value="cn=Manager" />
      <property name="password" value="secret" />
  </bean>

   <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="net.sf.ldaptemplate.LdapTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
   </bean>

<bean id="personDao" class="se.jayway.dao.PersonDaoImpl">
    <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
</bean>

   <bean id="contextSource2" class="net.sf.ldaptemplate.support.LdapContextSource">
      <property name="url" value="ldap://localhost:1389" />
      <property name="base" value="dc=jayway,dc=se" />
      <property name="userName" value="cn=Manager" />
      <property name="password" value="secret" />
  </bean>

   <bean id="ldapTemplate2" class="net.sf.ldaptemplate.LdapTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="contextSource2" />
   </bean>

<bean id="personDao2" class="se.jayway.dao.PersonDaoImpl">
    <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate2" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Then the java class defined as:

```
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {
   private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

   public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
      this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
   }
}
```

Notice that I have two connections defined. One for ldap at port 389 and one for port 1389. Then I use the PersonDaoImpl twice.

Herein lies the problem.

The PersonDao2 gets the same connection at 389 as PersonDao NOT the 1389 it is suppose to get.

**What can be causing this?**

Edit 2:

Here is a portion of the log file where I think we can see the problem

```
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'personDao'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'personDao'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'personDao' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ldapTemplate'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'ldapTemplate'
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'contextSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'contextSource'
DEBUG - AuthenticationSource not set - using default implementation
DEBUG - Not using LDAP pooling
DEBUG - Trying provider Urls: ldap://xxx.xx.xx.158:389/dc=domain,dc=com
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'ldapTemplate' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Added autowiring by name from bean name 'ldapTemplate' via property 'contextSource' to bean named 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'ldapTemplate'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'ldapTemplate'
DEBUG - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://xxx.xx.xx.158:389/dc=domain,dc=com'
DEBUG - Entered setLdapTemplate getContextSource() getReadOnlyContext() dc=domain,dc=com
DEBUG - Entered setLdaptreepathminusroot ou=people
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'personDao'
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'PersonDao2'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'PersonDao2'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'PersonDao2' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ldapTemplate2'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'ldapTemplate2'
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'contextSource2'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'contextSource2'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'contextSource2' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'contextSource2'
DEBUG - AuthenticationSource not set - using default implementation
DEBUG - Not using LDAP pooling
DEBUG - Trying provider Urls: ldap://xxx.xx.xx.147:389/dc=directory,dc=domain2,dc=com
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'contextSource2'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'ldapTemplate2' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Added autowiring by name from bean name 'ldapTemplate2' via property 'contextSource' to bean named 'contextSource'
DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'ldapTemplate2'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'ldapTemplate2'
DEBUG - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://xxx.xx.xx.158:389/dc=domain,dc=com'
DEBUG - Entered setLdapTemplate getContextSource() getReadOnlyContext() dc=domain,dc=com
DEBUG - Entered setLdaptreepathminusroot ou=individualprovider
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'PersonDao2'
```

It seems to me that the relevant two lines are

```
DEBUG - Added autowiring by name from bean name 'ldapTemplate' via property  'contextSource' to bean named 'contextSource'
```

and

```
DEBUG - Added autowiring by name from bean name 'ldapTemplate2' via property 'contextSource' to bean named 'contextSource'
```

Notice that both of these are getting

```
via property 'contextSource' to bean named 'contextSource'
```

The ldapTemplate2 should be getting:

```
via property 'contextSource' to bean named 'contextSource2'
```

Update:
I was asked to provide the code I am using to wire into my class.

The first way was this:

```
@Controller
public class ManageAccountsController{
    private PersonDaoImpl personDao2;
}
```

using this way I got no initialization of personDao2

The second way was this:

```
@Controller
public class ManageAccountsController{
    @Autowired PersonDaoImpl personDao2;
}
```

The third way was this:

```
@Controller
public class ManageAccountsController{
    @Autowired @Qualifier("personDao2") PersonDaoImpl personDao2;
}
```

These last 2 methods I got the incorrect contextSource. The contextSource of personDao.

Comment: can you show how you have autowired for DAO2 ?

Comment: I have updated the Question to show how the DAO2 is wired.

Comment: are you not getting exception for second way..because autowiring happens by type but it has more than one of that type ?

Comment: Correct. There are no exceptions.  I do agree with you. That is why I added the @Qualifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

I had to explicitly define the contextSource such as

```
<bean id="ldapTemplate2" class="net.sf.ldaptemplate.LdapTemplate">
    <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: yes i was suspected that there was a problem with constrcutor and qualifer and even i had mentioned in my answer..anyway good now..

Answer (score 2):

oh okie..as i know `@qualifier` has some problem with constrcutor injection..
can you try single annotation  `@Resource(name="personDao2")` instead of

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("personDao2")
```

...let me know the result..

Comment: Thanks for helping. I updated by question to include the annotation config as well as the component-scan. I already had these in my code i just had not defined them in my question. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced with @Resource(name="personDao2") and the results is that the context is still pointing to the incorrect ip address.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you have wired your `net.sf.ldaptemplate.LdapTemplate` explicitly in xml, but then you also have an `@Autowired` annotation on the `contextSource` property in `LdapTemplate`, this I believe is the problem. I would recommend you go ahead and remove the `@Autowired` altogether on the `LdapTemplate` class, this way only the xml based wiring takes effect.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I gave your answer a lot of thought. I have edited my Question to the 3 methods I tried. Your answer does make sense but for some reason I keep getting a null. The object is not initialized.

Comment: I have verified that the ldapcontextsource is the culprit. somehow it is not getting the correct url even though i set it in the xml.